# Cant change the values of a matrix using for loop

Tags: python

I have a matrix M with float numbers. I want to round said numbers to 3 decimals and update the matrix. However, M doesn't change.
Why is M not updating?

```
M= [[1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0, 0.5098039215686274], [-0.0, -0.0, 1.0, 0.4117647058823529]]
for arr in M:
    for number in arr:
        number = round(number, 3)
print(M) #[[1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0, 0.5098039215686274], [-0.0, -0.0, 1.0, 0.4117647058823529]]
```

Comment: `number` is the variable you use in the for loop, but changing that doesn't change `M`. You can use index and update say `M[i][j]`, or use what @Collin Bell answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change an array while iterating over it. Instead, store your changes elsewhere. You can set `M = rounded_M` at the end if you like.

```
M = [[1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0, 0.5098039215686274], [-0.0, -0.0, 1.0, 0.4117647058823529]]
rounded_M = []

for arr in M:
    rounded_arr = []
    for number in arr:
        rounded_arr.append(round(number, 3))
    rounded_M.append(rounded_arr)

print(rounded_M)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the line "number = round(number, 3)" do that?

Comment: When Python iterates over a list, it creates an iterator object in the background it's actually working on. The `number` you're updating isn't the same `number` as your list.

Answer (score 0):

basically you are not assigning anything to "M". you need to store the numbers that you are generating and round function just returns a value that you are assigning it to "number" and not "M".

```
M= [[1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0, 0.5098039215686274], [-0.0, -0.0, 1.0, 0.4117647058823529]]
temp2=list()
for arr in M:
    temp=list()
    for number in arr:
        number = round(number, 3)
        temp.append(number)
    temp2.append(temp)
print(temp2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're actually **not** changing the values within the list. To change (mutate) a list item, you must call the item by its index. (There are other ways, but this is the most common.) For example:

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
my_list[0] = 4 # Changes 0th item to 4
```

In your code, you were changing the `number` variable, but this won't affect the list. The best way, in this case, would be (as Collin stated) to **create a separate list.**

```
M = [[1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0, 0.5098039215686274], [-0.0, -0.0, 1.0, 0.4117647058823529]]

A = [] # New list to store the rounded numbers

for sublist in M:
    A.append([round(number, 3) for number in sublist])
```

The code above uses what are called **list comprehensions.** Esentially, they're like compact for-loops.  This code is saying: return an array of rounded numbers for every number in the sublist of `M` and add it to the new list `A`.

Answer (score 0):

that is because you are not passing the value back to M. Try this..

```
M = [[1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0, 0.5098039215686274], [-0.0, -0.0, 1.0, 0.4117647058823529]]
for arr in M:
    new_arr = [round(x, 3) for x in arr]
    arr[:] = new_arr[:]
print(M)  # [[1.0, 0.667, 0.0, 0.51], [-0.0, -0.0, 1.0, 0.412]]
```